# need to make top 10 strings and int's

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

im making plugin to game. I need to get 10 values from Config, and sort it in top 10. it should print top 10 like:

```
1. Name + points
2. Name + points
.
.
.
10. Name + points
```

With code which I pasted below, I received:

`[name1, name2, name3, name4][points1,points2,points3]`

**and it is not sorted like i would like to. It should be from highest to lowest [10 resoults]**

```
for (String g : Rpgg.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("Stats").getKeys(false)){
    // Set<String> g = Rpgg.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("Stats").getKeys(false);
    // int[] i1 = new int[]{i};
    int i = Rpgg.getConfig().getInt("Stats."+g+".pkt");
    l.add(i);

    a.add(g);
    Collections.sort(a);

    Collections.sort(l);
    map.put(g,i);
}

sorted_map.putAll(map);
Bukkit.broadcastMessage("lp:"+ "§4G:§6 " + a + "   §4pkt§6 " +  l);
```

Comment: Is it currently giving you lowest to highest?

Comment: It gives me lowest to highest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"It gives me lowest to highest."*

If you're currently getting lowest to highest, and you want it in reverse order, just use

- [`Collections.reverseOrder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/ja%2avase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28%29) - Returns a comparator that imposes the reverse of the natural ordering on a collection of objects that implement the Comparable interface.

In your case:

```
Collections.sort(a, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

---

`Collections.reverseOrder()` returns a `Comparator`. Use this `Collections.sort` overloaded method that takes a `Comparator` as an argument

```
public static void sort(List list, Comparator c)
```

---

**EDIT** - per user comment

> *"oK, now i wanna to change dat list into int and string. How to do that ?"*

What you should do is make a class that has a `name` field and a `score` field and make it implement `Comparable` like

```
public class User implements Comparable<User> {
    String name;
    int score;

    public User(String name, int score){
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public int compareTo(User user){
        return user.getScore() - this.getScore();
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getScore(){
        return score;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Name: " + name + " Score: " + score;
    }
}
```

Then you can just have `User objects` and have a `List<User>` that you can sort all in one without having to sort scores and names.

```
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
// populate list
Collections.sort(userList);
```

The `toString` method will give you the result as a String. Just print the `User` object

---

Test Run

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class UserDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        users.add(new User("Jim", 4398));
        users.add(new User("James", 9880));
        users.add(new User("Jane", 10238));
        users.add(new User("Jack", 5498));
        users.add(new User("Josh", 6530));
        users.add(new User("John", 12349));
        users.add(new User("Jim", 9438));
        users.add(new User("Jill", 12307));
        users.add(new User("Jimbo", 23454));
        users.add(new User("Jason", 5430));

        Collections.sort(users);

        for (User user : users) {
            System.out.println(user);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Name: Jimbo Score: 23454
Name: John Score: 12349
Name: Jill Score: 12307
Name: Jane Score: 10238
Name: James Score: 9880
Name: Jim Score: 9438
Name: Josh Score: 6530
Name: Jack Score: 5498
Name: Jason Score: 5430
Name: Jim Score: 4398
```

Comment: oK, now i wanna to change dat list into int and string. How to do that ?

Comment: You should make a class that has a name field and a score field and make it implement Comparable.

Comment: See my **EDIT** to see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a two dimensional array with your information instead of 2 single ones.